# I'm trying to send an email with node, nodemon, express and dotenv

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, sendgrid

I'm trying to send a email verification with a token verification, the code doesn't mark me any error, but when I use my route, it does not work, so I'm not sure why, All these are into a API development, I'm gonna leave the code.

First I'm leaving my server index:

```
//IMports
const express =  require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development' 


require('dotenv').config({path:__dirname+'/config.env'})

// Init app
const app = express();

// settings
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000)
app.use(cors({
 origin: process.env.PORT || 3003 //cors permite el uso de react
}))

app.use(morgan('dev'))//morgan debe dar información porcada petición



// middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//routes
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("welcome to api kiral")
});

app.use(require('./routes/Task.routes'))
app.use(require('./routes/Team.routes'))
app.use(require('./routes/Register.routes'))
app.use(require('./routes/Prueba.routes'))



// Start server
app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
    console.log(`Server on port ${app.get("port")}`);
});
```

How you can see it is calling an config.env with the path method so now I'll show you that document:

```
CLIENT_URL=https://localhost:3000
JWT_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION = 6f192f5a5dfe77993d390ec486aa00317c8e6f63f7661181313eb551f7a7b4c34c60641f57e94ccabdd8d5be2fe07dfda21651473e0a39
JWT_SECRET = 7643d1abcc6b9b04a6e50510953a76abcb5d72e2fe3e04a074dd9871e390c6d1214db7af574c0afc82d292aa96217aa647a88d3cc8accd4
JWT_RESET_PASSWORD = 192366c6415126025d84ed1953a76abcb5d72e2fe3e04a074dd9871e390c6d1214db7af574c0afc82d292aa96217aa647a88d3cc8accd4
EMAIL_FROM = ree@grro.com
MAIL_KEY = SG.G-2g7t60To6KMnXJEpg23aALV1CgKGOLiRGkNEbbv10hI
```

The mail key is because I'm using SendGrid/mail, so in this case, all these env variables is working.

How you can see on the index document I have routes, that is the next document.

```
const { Router } = require('express')
const router = Router();
const authController = require("../controllers/Register.controller");


//TAREAS

//GETS
router.get("/register", authController.getAuth)
router.get('/register/:email', authController.getAuths)


module.exports = router;
```

And at least, I have the code in charge of sending the email when it receives the user email.

```
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt')
const _ =require('lodash')
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const {validationResult} = require('express-validator')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
//Esto es para obtener el error de la  base de datos, se puede personalizar para hacerlo amigable.
const { errorHandler} =require('../helpers/dbErrorHandling')
//el siguiente const se usará para enviar correos
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.MAIL_KEY)

const pool = require('../database/connection')


class AuthController {
    async getAuth (req, res) {
        const result = await pool.query('select User_email from user');

        res.json({
            code: 200,
            message: "Prueba realizada con éxito",
            data: result
            
        });
    }


    async getAuths(req, res) {
    const email = (req.params.email);
    let sql = `select User_email from user where User_email = ${email}`;
    const mail = poo.query(sql);

    if(email.length = 0) {
        return res.json({
            code: 404,
            message: "Equipo no encontrado",
            data: [],
        })

    }else{
 

    //generate token

    const token = jwt.sign(
        {email}, 
         process.env.JWT_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION,
        {expiresIn: '1440m' }
    )

    const emailData = {
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
      to: email,
      subject: 'Account activation link',
      html: `
                <h1>Please use the following to activate your account</h1>
                <p>${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/register/${token}</p>
                <hr />
                <p>This email may containe sensetive information</p>
                <p>${process.env.CLIENT_URL}</p>
            `
    }

    sgMail.send(emailData).then(sent => {
        return res.json({
            message: `el email se ha enviado a ${email}`
        })
    }).cath(err => {
        return res.status(404).json({
            error: errorHandler(err)
        })
    })

    }

        
    }

}


const authController = new AuthController();
module.exports = authController;
```

I'm new working with APIS, and all looks fine, all the libraries coded are installed so that's right, and the code looks fine for me.

Comment: The way you have configured CORS is incorrect, a port number is not a valid option for origin - it should be the hostname. Something like the below would be more correct:

    app.use(cors({ origin: process.env.SERVER_HOST || 'localhost' }))

Comment: This line of code is incredibly dangerous:

    let sql = `select User_email from user where User_email = ${email}`;

You are basically giving anyone complete access to your database, you should look into [SQL injection attacks](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) and parameterised queries.

Comment: You've created a mail variable but not done anything with it and you have got a variable misspelled - poo instead of pool, this would likely cause issues too.

    const mail = poo.query(sql);

Comment: You also should add a `return` in front of the `sendMail` function call to ensure what you are returning in its callback is returned up the chain. I also wonder, can you confirm with the debugger/console.logs that the email address inside getAuths is coming through correctly as the @ symbol is not a URL safe character and would be encoded before being sent through

Comment: @th1nkful Ok, I'll make the changes, thank you for the support, I get this problem in the terminal 
sgMail.send(...).then(...).cath is not a function

Comment: the ‘cath’ should be catch! That is another syntax error that is going to be causing problems too

Comment: @th1nkful you are right, that's the kind of things in front of your nose but that you can't see, now I'm having an answer, an error but with that, I can work, I'll update for news

Comment: @th1nkful now it works, also the catch need be changed, I change the API for the email and now it works, thank you so much for your time, please add your comment as an answer for select it

Comment: Have added it as an answer, happy to help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the misspelling of catch as Cath may cause you some trouble along with the other things I’d commented, take a look and see if fixing those up helps you out!